# C# Sorting - not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, methods

Thanks for all the answers, As I said before, I am a beginner, so maybe I'll try to show my problem from the other side. At the beginning I wrote a working program like below, but then I realised my task was to use that sealed class and this is just too difficult for me at the moment.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Projekt_1__konsola
{
sealed class Element
{
    int val;
    public Element(int e)
    {
        val = e;
    }
    public int v
    {
        get
        {
            return val;
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void UstawienieStylu()
    {
        Console.Title = "Projekt";
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
        Console.Clear();
    }

    static void PodajLiczbę(string komunikat, out int liczba)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write(komunikat);
            string str = Console.ReadLine();
            try
            {
                liczba = int.Parse(str);
                break;
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Wprowadzono liczbę w złym formacie");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            }
            catch (OverflowException)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Wartość jest za duża albo za mała");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Napotkano koniec strumienia");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Spróbuj jeszcze raz");
        }
    }

    static void Sortuj(int[] tablica)
    {
        for (uint i = 1; i < tablica.Length; i++)
        {
            uint j = i;
            int buf = tablica[j];
            while ((j > 0) && (tablica[j - 1] > buf))
            {
                tablica[j] = tablica[j - 1];
                j--;
            }
            tablica[j] = buf;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UstawienieStylu();

        int liczba;
        PodajLiczbę("Podaj liczbę elementów do posortowania: ", out liczba);
        int element, i;
        int[] tablica = new int[liczba];
        for (i = 0; i < liczba; i++)
            {
                PodajLiczbę("Podaj element [" + i + "]: ", out element);
                tablica[i] = element;
            }

        Sortuj(tablica);

        Console.WriteLine("Posortowane elementy: ");
        for (i = 0; i < liczba; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Element [{0}] = {1}", i, tablica[i]);
        }
    }
}
}
```

I have a task to write a program which uses the exact class written at the beginning. Without it it would be easy, now it's not, as I'm a beginner with programming and especially with objects. What am I doing wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Projekt_1__konsola
{
sealed class Element
{
    int val;
    public Element(int e)
    {
        val = e;
    }
    public int v
    {
        get
        {
            return val;
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void UstawienieStylu()
    {
        Console.Title = "Projekt 1";
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
        Console.Clear();
    }

    static Element[] WczytajDaneZKonsoli()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string str = Console.ReadLine();
            int element;

            try
            {
                element = int.Parse(str);
                break;
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Wprowadzono liczbę w złym formacie");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            }
            catch (OverflowException)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Wartość jest za duża albo za mała, pamiętaj że możesz podać liczby z zakresu 1 do 4294967295");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Napotkano koniec strumienia");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Spróbuj jeszcze raz");
        }
    }

    static void Sortowanie(Element[] tablica)
    {
        for (uint i = 1; i < tablica.Length; i++)
        {
            uint j = i;
            int buf = tablica[j].v;
            while ((j > 0) && (tablica[j - 1].v > buf))
            {
                tablica[j].e = tablica[j - 1].v;
                j--;
            }
            tablica[j].e = buf;
        }
    }

    static void WyświetlDane(Element[] elementy)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Posortowane elementy: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < elementy.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Element [{0}] = {1}", i, elementy[i].v);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UstawienieStylu();
        Element[] elementy = WczytajDaneZKonsoli();
        Sortowanie(elementy);
        WyświetlDane(elementy);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: By the way, `ArgumentNullException` doesn't mean what your error message says it does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return `Element[]` from the following method

```
static Element[] WczytajDaneZKonsoli()
```

**Note:** Your function `WczytajDaneZKonsoli()` seems tobe doing nothing so you need to create an `Element[]` and return it.

you may want to add the following code to create the `Element[]` array as below:

```
static Element[] WczytajDaneZKonsoli()
{
    Element [] myElements = new Element[10]; //size depends on your equirements

   //or you can use Lis<Element> if you don't know the size
    int count = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        string str = Console.ReadLine();
        int element;

        try
        {
            element = int.Parse(str);
            myElements[count]=new Element(element);
            count++;
            break;
        }

     return myElements;
```

Comment: This code will never allow the user to enter more than one element, which defeats the purpose of this program (sorting elements).

Comment: @KonradMorawski: why not morethan one element, btw you should also consider the above code just describes how the OP hasto write his code , it's not complete implementation

Comment: Because you `break` out of the `while` loop after parsing the first number. The method will only ever return 1 element entered by the user. `Element[1]` to `Element[9]` will be null.

Comment: @KonradMorawski: yes but that logic depends on how OP wants to perform and Question is completly different `not all code paths return a value` and moreover i'm not breaking it's just his code...

Answer (score 0):

Your function `WczytajDaneZKonsoli` signature says it returns an `Element[]` but you're not returning anything. Just as the error message says, all codepaths for that function must return a value (or terminate due to exception).

The other option is to change the signature, but you must make sure that everywhere you're calling it, that it's not expecting it to return anything. For example, in `Program.Main()`.

Example of changing the signature.

```
static void WczytajDaneZKonsoli()
```

Comment: Arrays have no `.Add` method. Your code will never allow the user to enter more than one element.

Comment: OK. I forgot to add that my task also says, that each element of the table should be an object of Element class. And I have one more problem: in Sortowanie method I try to overwrite val, but it's private, so I can't and error shows up for those lines: tablica[j].**e** = tablica[j - 1].v; tablica[j].**e** = buf;

Answer (score 0):

Return a `Element[]` from the function

```
static Element[] WczytajDaneZKonsoli()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong.

You should be populating a collection of elements (number entered by the user) within your `WczytajDaneZKonsoli` method, but right now you're breaking out of your infinite `while` loop  after the very first number entered by the user, so there's no way they can ever enter more elements than just 1.

And obviously it's rather pointless sorting an array consisting of a single element.

Other suggested solutions (at the moment) don't tackle this issue.

You need to enable your user to make a decision whether they're done or want to add one more number still.

Once you get this right, initialize a collection of `Element` (could be a `List<Element>`, since you don't know in advance how many elements there will be) and keep on adding more elements to collection. Return `list.ToArray()` after the user decides there's no more numbers.

Working solution:

```
    static Element[] WczytajDaneZKonsoli()
    {
        List<Element> elements = new List<Element>();
        Console.WriteLine("Keep on entering numbers, enter X once you're done");
        Console.WriteLine("Podawaj liczby. Wpisz X aby zakończyć i przejść do sortowania.");
        while (true)
        {                
            string str = Console.ReadLine();
            if (str == "X")
            {
                break;
            }

            int element;
            try
            {
                element = int.Parse(str);
                elements.Add(new Element(element));
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Wprowadzono liczbę w złym formacie");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            }
            catch (OverflowException)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Wartość jest za duża albo za mała, pamiętaj że możesz podać liczby z zakresu 1 do 4294967295");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Napotkano koniec strumienia");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Spróbuj jeszcze raz");
        }
        return elements.ToArray();
    }
```